# extracting selected contacts from android phone

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm developing an app where in I need to display all the contacts to the user.
The user should be given an option to select multiple contacts and when he presses done, all of it must be stored in the DB.

Can anyone help me with the code to display and extract the selected contacts ??{ one no must be selected even when thr are multiple no for same name }

If u can just make the selected contacts' name to be displayed in a toast { I ll do the DB part on my own }, I ll be grateful...

Plz help.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own ListView of Contacts with `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` and use a `CheckTextView` for the individual item layout.  Below is a complete example.  It has the *Done* button on the action bar.

```
public class PickContactsActivity extends ListActivity {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setItemsCanFocus(false);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, 
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                null, null, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                cursor,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }, 
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private List<Uri> pickContacts() {
        SparseBooleanArray a = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
        List<Uri> contacts = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
            if (a.valueAt(i)) {
                Cursor c = (Cursor)mAdapter.getItem(a.keyAt(i));
                Long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contacts.add(ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id));
            }
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_pick:
            List<Uri> contacts = pickContacts();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Selected Contacts\n");
            for(Uri c : contacts)
                sb.append(c).append("\n");
            Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The *Done* action is defined in *res/menu/main.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_pick" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:title="Done"/>
</menu>
```

Finally, make sure you have the permission to read contacts.  Add this to *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Just remove the code that shows the Toast message and use the List of Uri perform your database operations.

Comment: Sir, there is one prblm.. The order of contacts being displayed is not alphabetically.. Its the order in which the contacts have been added... Can u plz help out??

Comment: I edited the answer to add the Order By clause to the query.  This will sort the contacts by DISPLAY_NAME.  Plz accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: The orderby clause added didn work.. Thr was an error. Instead, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC" worked :) Thanks again for the help :) :)